# ruby change color of label if conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'am just start to learn code (and english .. ) and  I have  a prob with ruby conditional . :O

I have an array, " Category" who depending to "Publication" post.

and i would like that the color of label to my category change in fonction to catgeory ?

( sorry for my english i work for learn ^^ )

It's  a part of my simple form for for post a product ( it 's false it's just for show my idea )

```
 <%= f.input :Category, collection:[" Application ", "Nature" ,"Design", "Science"], prompt: "Choisissez votre categorie"%>**
```

Its a part of my index view to all my product

```
<% if Category["Nature"]? %>
 <span class="label label-info">
 <h6><%= publication.Category %></h6>
</span>
<% else if Category["Tech"]? %>
 <span class="label label-sucess">
<h6><%= publication.Category %></h6>
</span>
<%end%>
```

thx for help

Comment: Use `elsif` instead of `else if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to the above suggestion would be to create a helper method.

```
def publication_label(category)
  colors = {
    'Nature'      => 'label-info',
    'Tech'        => 'label-success',
    'Application' => 'label-info'
  }

  content_tag(:span, class: "label #{colors[category]}") do
    content_tag(:h6, category)
  end
end
```

(Since you are probably also new to rails, you might be able to put that into /app/helpers/publications_helper.rb).

With that helper in place, your view can be as simple as:

```
<%= publication_label publication.Category %>
```

Comment: it's perfect ty :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a hash with category and their respective classes

```
color_hash = {
  "Nature" => 'label-info',
  "Tech" => 'label-success',
  "Application" => 'label-info'
}
```

And just pass the value of category in `publication.Category`

```
<span class="label <%= color_hash[publication.Category] %>">
  <h6><%= publication.Category %></h6>
</span>
```

if `publication.Category` is `"Tech"` the above code will be :

```
<span class="label label-success">
  <h6><%= publication.Category %></h6>
</span>
```